# ¿Como puedo llamar un array que esta dentro de un metodo a otro metodo dentro de la misma clase?

Tags: java, array, método, netbeans-8.2

Esto es lo llevo hasta el momento

```
public class Proyecto_progra1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String opcion;
    int num = 0;

    do{

    opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1- Nombre de conductores.\n"
            +"2- Placas de autobuses.\n"+"3- Rutas y precios. \n"+"4- Simulacion \n"
    +"5- Ganancias del dia.\n"+"6- Unidades y rutas\n"+"7- Salir");//Opciones para el usuario.

    if (opcion.matches ("[0-9]*"))//Se valida valor ingresado si es numero o letra
    {
    num = Integer.parseInt(opcion);//

    switch (num)
    {
        case 1 : nombre_conductores(); //Llamar metodo de nombre de conductores
        break;
        case 2: placas_buses(); //Llamar metodo donde se almacenan las placas de los buses.
        break;
        case 3: rutas_precios();// Llamar metodo donde se definen las rutas y los precios.
        break;
        case 4: simulacion();
        break;
        case 5: ganancia();
        break;
        case 6: unidades();
        break;
        case 7: System.exit(0);//Salir del programa
        break;
        default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite algunas de las opciones disponibles.");
    }
    }
    else

{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite un numero");
}
    } while(num!=4);//Se encicla programa hasta que el usuario decida salir.
}


 public static void nombre_conductores()
 {
  String [] nombre = new String[5]; //Se define arreglo.


 for( int i = 0; i<5; i++)
 {
     nombre[i]  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite nombre");// Se ingresan nombres de los choferes

 }
 for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
 {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los nombres son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+nombre[i]); // Se imprimen el nombre de los choferes
 }

}

 public static void placas_buses()
 {
    String [] placas = new String[6]; // Se define arreglo

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
    placas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite numeros de placas"); // Se ingresan el numeros de las placas
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<placas.length; i++)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las placas son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+placas[i]);// Se imprimen numeros de placa
    }
 } 

public static void rutas_precios()
{
     String [] rutas = new String[5]; // Se definen arreglo

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
    rutas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite ruta"); // Se ingresan rutas.
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<rutas.length; i++)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las rutas son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+rutas[i]);//Se imprimen rutas.
    }

    int [] precios = new int[5];// Se define arreglo

    for( int i =0; i<precios.length; i++)
    {
    precios[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+" -Digite precio"));// Se ingresan precios

    }

    for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los precios son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+precios[i]);// Se imprimen precios
    }

    for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ruta"+(i+1)+"-"+rutas[i]+ "\n"+"Precio "+precios[i]);// Se concatenan rutas y precios
    }
}
  public static void simulacion()
    { 
        String pasajeros;
        int entero;

        pasajeros = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numeros de pasajeros");

        if(pasajeros.matches("[0-9]*"))
        {
        entero = Integer.parseInt(pasajeros);



        }
        else
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero");
        }

 }

  public static void ganancia()
  {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aún en construcion");
  }


   public static void unidades()
   {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aún en construcion");
   }
}
```

En el metodo simulacion(), necesito un valor del arrays de nombre de conductores, un valor del array de las placas y un valor del array precios y rutas, las veces que he intentado llamarlo, se ejecuta el metodo nuevamente y tengo que volver a digitar los valores.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se podría hacer para tener los arrays disponibles entre métodos de la misma clase es definirlos de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Proyecto_progra1 {

    private static String[] placas;
    private static String[] rutas;
    private static int[] precios;
    private static String[] conductores; // En tu código figura como nombres pero lo puse conductores por un tema de claridad
```

Luego podes ir cargando estos arrays con cada una de las opciones que figuran en el menú. Finalmente cuando llegues al método llamado simulación si los cargastes con las otras opciones previamente, los valores de cada uno ya estarán disponibles, en caso contrario lo que deberías hacer es solicitar la carga (es decir si solicitas la carga de datos es porque no elegiste las otras opciones del menú previamente).

Tomando como referencia el código que tenes te dejo un ejemplo de como sería:

```
package programa;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Proyecto_progra1 {

    private static String[] placas;
    private static String[] rutas;
    private static int[] precios;
    private static String[] conductores;


    public static void nombre_conductores()
    {
         conductores= new String[5];
         for( int i = 0; i<5; i++)
         {
            conductores[i]  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite nombre");// Se ingresan nombres de los choferes

         }

         mostrarconductores();


    }



    public static void placas_buses()
     {
        placas = new String[6]; // Se define arreglo

        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
        placas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite numeros de placas"); // Se ingresan el numeros de las placas
        }


        mostrarplacas();
     } 

    public static void mostrarplacas()
    {
         for(int i = 0; i<placas.length; i++)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las placas son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+placas[i]);// Se imprimen numeros de placa
          }
    }
    public static void mostrarrutas()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<rutas.length; i++)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las rutas son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+rutas[i]);//Se imprimen rutas.
        }

    }
    public static void mostrarprecios()
    {

          for(int i =0; i<precios.length; i++)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los precios son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+precios[i]);// Se imprimen precios
            }
    }

    public static void mostrarconductores()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i<conductores.length; i++)
         {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los nombres son:\n"+(i+1)+"-"+conductores[i]); // Se imprimen el nombre de los choferes
         }

    }

    public static void rutas_precios()
    {
        rutas = new String[5]; // Se definen arreglo

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
        rutas[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+"-Digite ruta"); // Se ingresan rutas.
        }
        mostrarrutas();

        precios = new int[5];// Se define arreglo

        for( int i =0; i<precios.length; i++)
        {
        precios[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog((i+1)+" -Digite precio"));// Se ingresan precios

        }    
        mostrarprecios();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String opcion;
        int num = 0;

        do{

        opcion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1- Nombre de conductores.\n"
                +"2- Placas de autobuses.\n"+"3- Rutas y precios. \n"+"4- Simulacion \n"
        +"5- Ganancias del dia.\n"+"6- Unidades y rutas\n"+"7- Salir");//Opciones para el usuario.

        if (opcion.matches ("[0-9]*"))//Se valida valor ingresado si es numero o letra
        {
        num = Integer.parseInt(opcion);//

        switch (num)
        {
            case 1 : nombre_conductores(); //Llamar metodo de nombre de conductores
            break;
            case 2: placas_buses(); //Llamar metodo donde se almacenan las placas de los buses.
            break;
            case 3: rutas_precios();// Llamar metodo donde se definen las rutas y los precios.
            break;
            case 4: simulacion();
            break;
            case 5: ganancia();
            break;
            case 6: unidades();
            break;
            case 7: System.exit(0);//Salir del programa
            break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite algunas de las opciones disponibles.");
        }
        }
        else

    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite un numero");
    }
        } while(num!=4);//Se encicla programa hasta que el usuario decida salir.
    }

      public static void simulacion()
        { 
            String pasajeros;
            int entero;

            pasajeros = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numeros de pasajeros");

            if(pasajeros.matches("[0-9]*"))
            {
            entero = Integer.parseInt(pasajeros);

            if (conductores!=null)
                     mostrarconductores();
            else nombre_conductores();

            if (placas!=null)
                  mostrarplacas();
            else  placas_buses();

            if (rutas==null && precios==null)
                rutas_precios();
            else {       
                     mostrarrutas();
                     mostrarprecios();
             }


            }
            else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero");
            }

    }

      public static void ganancia()
      {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aún en construcion");
      }


       public static void unidades()
       {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aún en construcion");
       }



}
```

La pequeña modificación que hice por un tema de reuso mas que nada es que cree los siguientes métodos para imprimir los arrays, eso adaptalo como vos prefieras.

1. mostrarconductores();
2. mostrarplacas();
3. mostrarrutas();
4. mostrarprecios();

Dentro del método simulación, le puse este código para que si no elegiste la carga de alguno te la solicite directamente en dentro de esto método, en caso contrario te imprime los valores cargados para cada array en pantalla.

```
         if (conductores!=null)
                 mostrarconductores();
        else nombre_conductores();

            if (placas!=null)
                  mostrarplacas();
            else  placas_buses();

            if (rutas==null && precios==null)
                rutas_precios();
            else {       
                     mostrarrutas();
                     mostrarprecios();
             }
```

Saludos y espero que sea de tu utilidad.